# Expected value of the maximum of a vector with multivariate distribution and arbitrary dimensions

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to find `E[Max(x1,x2,...,xn)]`, but the following does not seem to work:

```
Expectation[Max[x], x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[3]]
```

while this does:

```
Expectation[Max[{x[1], x[2], x[3]}], {x[1], x[2], x[3]} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[3]]
```

Returning a value of `3/4`, which is the correct value (general solution is `n/(n+1)`).

What seems to be happening is that `Max[x]` is immediately simplified to `x`. Is there any was to prevent this if this is indeed the cause? Otherwise, how would you go about modifying the above code to provide solutions for arbitrary `n`?

Comment: You could use `OrderDistribution[]` at least in this case: `Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], 3}, 3]]`

Comment: .. or `Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], n}, n]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Expectation[x, Distributed[x, OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], n}, n]]]
```

> n/(1 + n)

or

```
Mean @ OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], n}, n]
```

> n/(1 + n)